# pearsons linear coefficient keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, metrics, pearson-correlation

I have tried to implement pearsons linear coefficient as a metric in Keras however because of placeholders I cannot compile my model using this metric.

```
def CC(y_true, y_pred):

y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1)
y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1)
n_y_true=y_true/(K.sum(y_true)+K.epsilon())
n_y_pred=y_pred/(K.sum(y_pred)+K.epsilon())
y_true_average=K.mean(y_true)
y_pred_average=K.mean(y_pred)
print((K.map_fn(lambda x: x-y_pred_average,n_y_pred)).shape[0])
if not(K.map_fn(lambda x: x-y_pred_average,n_y_pred)).shape[0]==None:
    return (K.sum(K.dot((K.map_fn(lambda x: x-y_pred_average,n_y_pred)),(K.map_fn(lambda x: x-y_true_average,n_y_true))))/(K.count_params(n_y_true)-1))/(K.dot(K.std(n_y_pred),K.std(n_y_true)))
else:
    return 0
```

I tried using K.dot instead of * however the same error remains. During compile I get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType`. And I cannot figure out how to solve it. It happens because I want to elementwise multiply two tensors but the batchsize in the shape is not difined during compile and represented as a ? in the shape of (?,224,224,3). Is there a way to set this or work around it?

Comment: What is a shape of your target?

Comment: also (?,224,224,3) as I try to multiply every element in one tensor with its corresponding element (same index) in the other tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final function:

```
def CC(y_true, y_pred):


    #normalise
    n_y_true = (y_true - K.mean(y_true[:])) / K.std(y_true[:])
    n_y_pred = (y_pred - K.mean(y_pred[:])) / K.std(y_pred[:])  

    top=K.sum((n_y_true[:]-K.mean(n_y_true[:]))*(n_y_pred[:]-K.mean(n_y_pred[:])),axis=[-1,-2])
    bottom=K.sqrt(K.sum(K.pow((n_y_true[:]-K.mean(n_y_true[:])),2),axis=[-1,-2])*K.sum(K.pow(n_y_pred[:]-K.mean(n_y_pred[:]),2),axis=[-1,-2]))

    result=top/bottom


    return K.mean(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in two facts:

1. The first dimension of a tensor is a batch dimension (that's why during model compilation is set to `None`).
2. You are using `sum` and `mean` in such manner that you are also including this additional dimension in your computations.

Your Pearson's correlation loss should look the following:

```
def pearson_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1)
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1)
    # reshape stage
    y_true = K.reshape(y_true, shape=(-1, 224 * 224 * 3))
    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, shape=(-1, 224 * 224 * 3))
    # normalizing stage - setting a 0 mean.
    y_true -= y_true.mean(axis=-1)
    y_pred -= y_pred.mean(axis=-1)
    # normalizing stage - setting a 1 variance
    y_true = K.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=-1)
    y_pred = K.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=-1)
    # final result
    pearson_correlation = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1)
    return pearson_correlation
```

Comment: hmm, ok thank you! However why do none of the other losses from keras reshape? e.g. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py

Comment: Because they assume a completely different `y_true` and `y_pred` shapes.

Comment: huh they also asume a shape of (batch, inputchannels) right? How else will they be able to compute the loss of batches?

Comment: What correlation do you want to compute exactly? Channels against channels or whole images?

Comment: grayscale image vs grayscale image

Comment: But your image seems to be `RGB` images

Comment: sorry I am doing both and when I asked the question it was rgb and at the moment i am working with grayscale so i messed up my answer. Yes it is rgb image vs rgb image

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out, the problem was `(K.count_params(n_y_true)-1))` as it multiplies every element of n_y_true.shape and because n_y_true is derived from y_true it has the shape (?,?,?).